# How to allow Microsoft Team attendees to bypass lobby programatically (Microsoft Graph)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I've created an event on a calendar using Calendar API which in turn in the response, it will give me the link to a Microsoft Team meeting link. This is an example data that I've send when creating the event. Also, I'm calling this API as an App not as a user, so basically all 3 attendees are not part of the AD users.

```
{
        "attendees": [
            {
                "type": "required",
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": "attendee1@domain.com",
                    "name": "Attendee 1"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "required",
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": "attendee2@domain.com",
                    "name": "Attendee 2"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "required",
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": "attendee3@domain.com",
                    "name": "Attendee 3"
                }
            }
        ],
        "end": {
            "dateTime": "2020-11-13T17:32:39.636Z",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "start": {
            "dateTime": "2020-11-11T16:32:39.636Z",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "subject": "My online meeting",
        "isOnlineMeeting": true,
        "body": {
            "content": "Does this time work for you?",
            "contentType": "HTML"
        },
        "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness",
        "allowNewTimeProposals": false
    }
```

In the response, I receive something like this:

```
...
"onlineMeeting": {
    "joinUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_NzRmMDIwMWEtNGYyZS00MmNkLTk3NTAtOGxxxxkOGQ4ZDUx%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%22b82fec80-bee7-401e-xxxx-8a312e0a62d1%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22112d58ba-xxxx-47ce-a1a8-3d0abebead18%22%7d"
  }
...
```

My problem right now is none of the attendees can start the meeting. I wonder if there's a way programatically either when I'm creating the event or updating the online meeting, to enable the attendees to bypass the lobby and start the meeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your parameter, I think you use Calendar event api to create an online meeting.

I also tried this and found that the attendees needs permission to enter the meeting room while the creater can enter directly. I googled and found **no graph api could modify this configuration**. **The only way** to make every attendee join the meeting without permission is changing the meeting option as '**everyone can bypass the lobby**'

[image]

By the way, admin role account can login the **Microsoft teams admin center** and automatically allow people in your organization bypass the lobby. This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/85270/teams-meeting-bypass-the-lobby.html) tells the detail.

Actually, I used Fiddler to catch the changing option request and got a url like `https://teams.microsoft.com/api/mt/amer/beta/meetings/v1/options/....` and an access token. I can use them to change the option successfully by sending a http post request. All seems the answer will appear but unfortunately after analizing the access token I found the api needs a permission `https://api.spaces.skype.com` which is not supported by Azure ad.

Comment: Thank you, I finally settles on making a new policy that allows the bypass and automatically admit people in the meeting. For other people, please note that a policy will take around 24 hours to kicks in. So, patience is virtue